# An array in a class that contains all objects called from outside of the class

Tags: ruby, class

When I create a class object, I want my method to put my class objects into an array. And also it must be reachable outside the class. I tried to like this:

```
class Object1
  @@obj_all = []
  attr_accessor :id, :name
  def initialize id, name
    @id = id
    @name = name
    @@obj_all << self
  end
  def self.obj_all
    @@obj_all
  end
end

a1 = Object1.new(0,"A")
a2 = Object1.new(1,"A")
a3 = Object1.new(2,"A")
a4 = Object1.new(3,"A")
p Object1.obj_all
```

The result is ok, but when I want to use `p obj_all` instead of `p Object1.obj_all`, there is an error.

As you see, I can do this problem like that:

```
all_obj = []
all_obj[0] = Object1.new(0,"A")
all_obj[1] = Object1.new(1,"A")
all_obj[2] = Object1.new(2,"A")
all_obj[3] = Object1.new(3,"A")
```

so I have an 'all_obj' array and this is editable as I want. but I want to fix this problem inside our Object1 class.

How can I do as I want?

Comment: `Object1.obj_all`, as you see, is 'reachable' outside the class.

Comment: What do you want to do? Simply `p obj_all`? If that is the case, then as you have seen, you can't.

Comment: `def obj_all; Object1.obj_all; end`? But why? (Also, your terminology is weird. "put my class objects into a class" does absolutely not describe what your code is doing - "put my instances into a class attribute" does.)

Comment: I want to reach the 'obj_all' array outside the class, and add or remove some elements. so I tried to change my self method codes to any method inside the class but I can't do what I want, thx.

Comment: You can reach `obj_all` method outside the class since it's public method of your class object.

Comment: @MarekLipka I think he means globally e.g. in the context of `Object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding of the question is correct you can achieve what you want be redefining [Class::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Class.html#method-c-new). As that is a class method, the redefinition must be done within `Object1`'s singleton class. The scope is changed to the singleton class by invoking `class << self`, and that remains the active scope until the associated `end` is reached.

```
class Object1
  attr_accessor :name
  @obj_all = []

  def initialize name
    @name = name
  end

  class << self
    attr_reader :obj_all  
    def new(name)
      obj_all << super
      obj_all.last
    end 
  end
end

Object1.new('Bob')
  #=> #<Object1:0x00007ffcf49c7f40 @name="Bob">
Object1.new('Sal')
  #=> #<Object1:0x00007ffcf49bfef8 @name="Sal">
Object1.new('Eva')
  #=> #<Object1:0x00007ffcf49b6bc8 @name="Eva">

Object1.obj_all
  #=> [#<Object1:0x00007ffcf49c7f40 @name="Bob">,
  #    #<Object1:0x00007ffcf49bfef8 @name="Sal">,
  #    #<Object1:0x00007ffcf49b6bc8 @name="Eva">]
Object1.obj_all.map(&:name)
  #=> ["Bob", "Sal", "Eva"]
```

See the doc for the keyword [super](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-super).